# What is the best way of implementing stack and queues in python, without using any modules?

Tags: python, data-structures, stack, queue

I have tried `collections.deque` and `queue.Lifoqueue` for implementing stacks and queue, while both of them works fine, I want to implement it from scratch. So which is the best method according to time and space complexity? I have tried implementing it by singly linked list and through python list function. Is there any other method better than this?

Comment: Better in what sense? For example, a `list` will function perfectly well as a stack, what would you like to improve?

Comment: In the documentation for collections.OrderedDict, they give a possible implementation of OrderedSet.  OrderedSet is implemented using a doubly-linked list.  You can probably take that implementation, and toss the "set" part of it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, you are absolutely right that `list` will function perfectly but it has its own shortcomings regarding speed and memory allocation if the stack grows. So better in a sense where we have quicker pop and append without the above-mentioned shortcomings and without using any module.

Comment: @DhruvSharma what shortcomings exactly? Python list objects have amortized constant time append and pop. Given that they are implemented in C, below the interpreter layer, it's doubtful that you will find an effectively faster data structure in *pure* python to make a stack.

Answer (score 0):

here is the queue. I commented time complexity for each operation

```
class QueuesArray:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data=[]
    def __len__(self): # O(1)
        return len(data)
    def isempty(self): # O(1)
        return len(self._data)==0
    def enqueue(self,e): #O(1)
        self._data.append(e)
        return e
    def dequeue(self): # O(1)
        if self.isempty():
            return ValueError("")
        return self._data.pop(0) # O(1)
    def first(self): # O(1)
        if self.isempty():
            print ('Queue is empty')
        return self._data[0]
```

here is stack:

```
class StacksArray:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data=[]
    def __len__(self): # O(1)
        return len(self._data)
    def isempty(self): # O(1)
        return len(self._data)==0
    def push(self,e): # O(1)
        self._data.append(e)
        return e
    def pop(self): # O(1)+O(1)
        if self.isempty(): # O(1)
            print('stack is empty')
            raise IndexError
        else:
            return self._data.pop() # O(1)
    def top(self): # O(1)+O(1)
        if self.isempty(): # O(1)
            print('stack is empty')
            raise IndexError
        return self._data[-1] # O(1)
```